# Why does the elevated command prompt end with a ">" (greater than) instead of "\" (backslash)?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, prompt

When I open an elevated command prompt I am greeted with a strange first line. Instead of the normal:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\
```

I am greeted with

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

This leaves me with "greater-than" `>` symbol instead of a backslash `\`. Is this correct?

Comment: Do you just want to set your prompt to $P\ instead of $P$G?  Or is there some other problem beyond the cosmetic one?

Comment: The default prompt ends with a `>` and has since DOS times.

Comment: what are DOS times? and I can not understand how to make commands. I need to make the command **C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\** but I cant with the >

Comment: DOS times means since DOS was the main OS.  The '>' shouldn't affect you, it's just cosmetic.  And that's not a command, that's a directory.  Are you trying to change to that directory?  Are you trying to edit a file in that directory?

Comment: @Destiny *C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc* is not a command.  Once you open the cmd prompt as admin, type "cd drivers" without the quotes and hit enter.  Then, type "cd etc" without the quotes and hit enter, and you will be in C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc

Comment: @destiny.  No... you just didn't know.  Now you do :)

Comment: i have another question .

Comment: @destiny Open a new question and we'll be happy to answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

The command prompt ending with a > seems to be normal.
[image: example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

I can add more, but those are just random Windows 7 command prompt images I dug up with google.

When I open cmd on W7, it ends with >.  When I open it as admin, it ends with >.  When I open cmd on XP, it ends with >.

Comment: yes but i can't make any commands !

Comment: @destiny: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you *really* want to put your install key on the internet? ;p

Comment: It's not my install key.  I just found the image in a google search.  That said... I'm sure that it was NOT a good idea for that person to put that image up.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it seems you are trying to execute a command (program, executable) under `C:\WINDOWS\system32\`. What you are seeing is *the prompt*, and it shows you the current directory. In Windows, you can run commands in the current directory simply by typing the name, e.g. `.\drivers\etc`.

By the way, if the command you are trying to run is directly under system32 (so `...\system32\notepad`, but not `...\system32\drivers\etc`), you can just type the name of the command no matter what your current directory is, e.g. `notepad`. This is because `C:\Windows\system32\` is in your [`%PATH%`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/books/5445775168.htm).